# SciPy.optimize.least_squares() 5PL Curve Optimization problems

Tags: python, curve, scipy-optimize

I am trying to write a script that will take an input array of x and y values and fit them to a 5-PL curve (defined by the equation F(x) = D+(A-D)/((1+(x/C)^B)^E)).  I then want to be able to use the predicted curve to take a given y value and extrapolate an x value from the curve, given by the equation F(y) = C(((A-D)/(-D+y))^(1/E)-1)^(1/B).

The answer below fixed the previous error, but the fit is still really bad.  I've introduced a print function with a handful of y values across the range fed into curve_fit, and it yields almost the exact same x value across the range.  Any ideas what may be going on here?

Edit:  For anyone looking now, the problem appears to have been my estimate for B.  The hill slope should be between -1 and 1 in most cases, not in the thousands.  That made it too far to estimate.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sp


def logistic5(x, A, B, C, D, E):
    '''5PL logistic equation'''
    log = D + (A-D)/(np.power((1 + np.power((x/C), B)), E))
    return log


def residuals(p, y, x):
    '''Deviations of data from fitted 5PL curve'''
    A, B, C, D, E = p
    err = y - logistic5(x, A, B, C, D, E)
    print(err)
    return err


def log_solve_for_x(curve, y):
    '''Returns the estimated x value for the provided y value'''
    A, B, C, D, E = curve
    return C*(np.power((np.power(((A-D)/(-D+y)), (1/E))-1), (1/B)))


# Toy data set
x = np.array([130, 38, 15, 4.63, 1.41])
y = np.array([9121, 1987, 1017, 343, 117])

# Set initial guess for parameters
A = np.amin(y)  # Min asymptote
D = np.amax(y)  # Max asymptote
B = (D-A)/(np.amax(x)-np.amin(x))  # Steepness
C = (np.amax(x)-np.amin(x))/2  # inflection point
E = 1  # Asymmetry factor

# Optimize curve for initial parameters
p0 = [A, B, C, D, E]
# set bounds for each parameter
pu = []
pl = []
for p in p0:
    pu.append(p*1.5)
    pl.append(p*0.5)
print(pu)
print(pl)
print("Initial guess of parameters is: ", p0)
curve = sp.least_squares(fun=residuals, x0=p0, args=(y, x), bounds=(pl, pu))
curve = curve.x.tolist()
print("Optimized curve parameters are: ", curve)

# Predict x values based on given y
y = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000]
for sample in y:
    solve = log_solve_for_x(curve, sample)
    print("Predicted X value for y =", sample, " is: ", solve)
```

Comment: I can recommend you to debug or to print the parameters that you pass to the `np.power`. The last value before the exception should be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curve is defined not for any values of parameters. But you did not provide that information for `least_squares`. At some point, the solver goes to an inadmissible zone and gets stuck there obtaining nans from `residuals` and you get messages about invalid power. You have trivial powers and may just set the `E>=0, B>=0`. But your base is non-trivial. You either need to switch to a solver that supports generic constraints (e.g. `scipy.optimize.minimize`) and add constraints that `base >=0` or somehow else restrict the search to the admissible domain, e.g.:

```
pu = []
pl = []
for p in p0:
    pu.append(p*1.5)
    pl.append(p*.5)

curve = sp.least_squares(fun=residuals, x0=p0, args=(y, x), bounds=(pl, pu))
```

You also may try to fix your residual that it works for any parameters, e.g. replace nan with distance to the initial guess. But it may work inefficiently.

---

To improve fitting results you may try a better initial point or multistart or both.

```
A = np.amin(y)  # Min asymptote
D = np.amax(y)  # Max asymptote
B = (D-A)/np.amax(x)*10  # Steepness
C = np.amax(x)/10  # inflection point
E = 0.001  # Asymmetry factor

p0 = [A, B, C, D, E]
print("Initial guess of parameters is: ", p0)
pu = []
pl = []
for p in p0:
    pu.append(p*1.5)
    pl.append(p*.5)

best_cost = np.inf
for i in range(100):
    for i in range(5):
        p0[i] = np.random.uniform(pl[i], pu[i])

    curve = sp.least_squares(fun=residuals, x0=p0, args=(y, x), bounds=(pl, pu))
    print(p0, curve.cost)
    if best_cost > curve.cost:
        best_cost = curve.cost
        curve_out = curve.x.tolist()
print("Optimized curve parameters are: ", curve_out)

plt.plot(x, y, '.')

xx = np.linspace(0, 150, 100)
yy = []
for x in xx:
    yy.append(logistic5(x, *curve_out))

plt.plot(xx, yy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Implementing the bounds seems to have cleared out the error, but I'm still getting a really weird curve that doesn't fit the data well at all.  Any ideas what the problem might be here?

Comment: @atyler, fitting is an art. The optimization problem you get has many local optimal. 
You may try a better initial point or multistart or both. I do not know that you want to fit, and cannot judge if the result is reasonable, but I updated the post with multistart based on different initial guesses and the curve is close to the training sample.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try these out and see how they work.  That definitely looks like a much better fit than I was getting before.